# Redirect rule in IIS not applying

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, redirect

I have the following problem:

i want to let the users of an exact url redirect to another one. 
Note: my URL immediately downloads a file.

What i want is to let the file forward to another file (it needs to download the file i'm redirecting to).

My Rule:

```
<rule name="File" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="https://SITE.be/download/DownloadFile?id=138999" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="https://SITE.be/download/DownloadFile?id=138999" />
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="https://SITE.be/download/DownloadFile?id=138999" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://SITE.be/download/DownloadFile?id=138111" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
```

my rule isn't working, it doesn't redirect it and when i check 'URL redirect checkers' it mentions that there isn't a redirect set on the URL.

what am i doing wrong?

Edit:

I tried:

```
<rule name="File" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="download/DownloadFile?id=138999" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
               <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^site.be$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://site.be/download/DownloadFile?id=138111" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
```

with no improving (redirect checkers on google still don't trigger that theres a redirect set)

Comment: Mistake 1 https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: thanks for your comment. this doesn't work however ,@LexLi . could it be cause this is a file?

Comment: You might make multiple mistakes, so please edit your question to reflect what you changed and what "doesn't work however". I don't expect you to get it right in a single round.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i edited my question

Comment: FRT trace should tell https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: i'm thinking hte question mark and slash have something to do with it (in my URL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your iis rewirte code, I find it has problem in match url part.
This part could only match the [download/DownloadFile] not the querystring.
If we want to check the query string id, we should use url rewrite condition.

More details, you could refer to below url rewrite rule.

```
<rule name="File" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="download/DownloadFile" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="id=138999" />
                         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^site.be$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://site.be/download/DownloadFile?id=138111" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
```

Or

```
<rule name="File" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="sitebe" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="download/DownloadFile\?id=138999" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://site.be/download/DownloadFile?id=138111" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
```